# How to know the point of the second tap on GestureDetector?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have the following gesture detector on Xamarin.Android (but probably the same applies for native android since classes are the same)

```
public class GestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{
    public override bool OnDown(MotionEvent e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"OnDown: {e.GetX()} {e.GetY()}");

        return false;
    }

    public override bool OnDoubleTap(MotionEvent e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"OnDoubleTap: {e.GetX()} {e.GetY()}");

        return true;
    }
}
```

The output from the debug when double tap is detected is

```
OnDown: 667.3821 861.5184
OnDoubleTap: 667.3821 861.5184
OnDown: 667.3821 861.5184
```

First log is for the first tap and the following 2 is for the second, the log is always for the same point (the first). The problem I have is that I need both points to see distance between them (double tap is being triggered with 2 taps in a row on any part of the screen and that's not what I need, I want them near)

How can I get both points?

Comment: Have you checked my answer? Any problem?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I have is that I need both points to see distance between them.

To calculate the distance between two touch points, we can implement the `GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener` interface and them simply calculate in the `OnTouchEvent` for example like this:

```
public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
{
    _gestureDetector.OnTouchEvent(e);
    var count = e.PointerCount;
    if (count == 2)
    {
        //distance
        float x = e.GetX(0) - e.GetX(1);
        float y = e.GetY(0) - e.GetY(1);
        var distance = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        Console.WriteLine("distance:" + distance);

        //center point
        float xx = e.GetX(0) + e.GetX(1);
        float yy = e.GetY(0) + e.GetY(1);
        var midpoint = new PointF(x / 2, y / 2);
    }
    return false;
}
```

To implement the `GestureDetector.IOnGestureListener` interface, you can refer to [Create a Gesture Listener](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/gestures/create_a_gesture_listener/).